# Data structure in python containing shapes corners and centroids

Tags: python, data-structures

I am having a lot of troubles in python programming, mostly because I am a beginner.

I first applied findContours to a picture and I have to save the retrieved shape corners and the shapes centroids in data structure for latter modifications.

I created a data structure for the shapes that looks like this (the number of shapes is not known):

```
Shapes = [[shape1-Corners],
          [shape2-Corners],
          [shape3-Corners],
          [...]
          [shapeN-Corners]]
```

and another one containing the centers (again the number of shapes is not known):

```
Centers = [x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2,...,xn, yn]
```

Now I have to access the data in those two structures and perform the pointPolygonTest to check if a shape is inside another one, but OF COURSE it's really hard (because I understand that this solution with two data structure is not really the best)

That's the code I wrote for accessing the data structure:

```
for k in range(0, len(centers), 2):
    nowcx = centers[k]
    nowcy = centers[k+1]
    for j in range(len(shapes)):
        if cv2.pointPolygonTest(shapes[j],(nowcx, nowcy),False)==1:
            print "inside"
        else:
            print "outside"
```

For easier understanding, this is the picture with the centroids in red. You can see that thare are 3 shapes: triangle, square and pentagon. So the data structures contain 3 records for the 3 shapes and 6 elements for the 3 centroids.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vibl0h0y4ses1za/graph.png

The output gives me 9 comparisons, when they should be actually 3:

1. triangle against square -> outside
2. triangle against pentagon -> inside
3. square againstr pentagon -> inside

That's the output:

```
inside
outside
inside
outside
inside
inside
inside
outside
inside
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself, of course with the help of Uri (thanks!!)

First of all, I changed the data structure, instead of having two data structure now I have only one. This data structure is made in this way:

```
Shapes = [[shape1-Corners],[CenterX, CenterY],
          [shape2-Corners],[CenterX, CenterY],
          [shape3-Corners],[CenterX, CenterY],
          [...]
          [shapeN-Corners],[CenterX, CenterY]]
```

Meaning that the centroid is saved right after the corner points of the shape.

After this, the access of the data structure is made in this way:

```
for k in range(1, len(shapes), 2):
    nowcx = shapes[k][0][0] #x coordinate of the center
    nowcy = shapes[k][0][1] #y coordinate of the center
    for z in range(k+1, len(shapes), 2):
        if cv2.pointPolygonTest(shapes[z],(nowcx, nowcy),False)==1:
            print "inside"
        else:
            print "outside"
```

And the output is (as hoped):

```
outside
inside
inside
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting the two loops, when you actually don't want to do that.
With the nested loop, for *each center*, you are checking *all* shapes. What you want to do is for each center test the appropriate polygon.

```
for k in range(0, len(centers), 2):
    nowcx = centers[k]
    nowcy = centers[k+1]
    if cv2.pointPolygonTest(shapes[k/2],(nowcx, nowcy),False)==1:
        print "inside"
    else:
        print "outside"
```

You could do a little bit cleaner and more "Pythonian" by using the zip(*[iter(s)]*n) idiom to cluster the centers list to tuples of two values:

```
for point, shape in zip(zip(*[iter(centers)]*2), shapes):
    if cv2.pointPolygonTest(shape, point, False):
        print "inside"
    else:
        print "outside"
```

Comment: the first solution you gave me actually works with putting shapes[k/2] in the pointPolygonTest. So that line of code would be: if cv2.pointPolygonTest(shapes[k/2],(nowcx, nowcy),False)==1:

Comment: By the way, your solution does not solve the problem. It actually compare each centroid with it's own shape and not against the others.